# Accessing properties in union types

Tags: typescript

Please consider the simple union type example below:

```
interface Alarm {
    alarmText: string,
    quali: number
}

interface Car {
    speed: number
}

type unionT = Alarm | Car;


var alarm: Alarm = {
    alarmText: "ALARM!!!",
    quali: 42
};

var bar: unionT = alarm;

bar.alarmText // ERROR
```

When the type unionT consist of different interfaces like `Alarm` and `Car` I cannot access the `alarmText` property anymore. The way I understand it is that the compiler cannot infer that I am referring to the alarm object. Only non-disjoint properties can be accessed in union types. Right?

If this is correct, how can I ever get my original alarm object back once it is declared in a variable of the union type? 
I first though that I could do a type guard like

```
if (typeof bar === 'Alarm') {
    bar.alarmText
}
```

But `typeof bar` is just `'object'` and thus the gaurd does not make any sense.

Anyone?

Comment: By the way, this works without a change with TypeScript 2.3

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom type guard to achieve this:

```
function isAlarm(a: Alarm | Car): a is Alarm {
    // Some check to see if this is an Alarm
    return (<Object>a).hasOwnProperty('alarmText');
}


if (isAlarm(bar)) {
    bar.alarmText;
}
```